# How do I bind a Boolean array to a C# model using Entity Framework Code First?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-migrations

I am trying to serialize a JSON response into a Entity Framework Code First model.

The payload is as follows:

```
[{
 "_cs_regimen":"3_per_week",
 "_cs_account_email":"my@email.com",
 "_cs_results":[true,true,false], <<< ### The property in question ###
 "_cs_distance":[101018.52287999999,460594.25279999996],
 "_cs_joined_team_time":"2022-06-11T10:36:15.840649Z",
 "_cs_account_lastName":...
```

My model is as follows:

```
public class LeaderboardData
{
    [Key]
    public int LeaderboardId { get; set; }

    [DefaultValue(1)]
    public int Week { get; set; }
    ......

    public virtual LeaderboardRideResult _cs_results { get; set; } < I want to bind the boolean array into this property.
}
```

LeaderboardRideResult looks like this:

```
public class LeaderboardRideResult
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string tag { get; set; }

    public List<bool> contents { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("LeaderboardData")]
    public int LeaderboardDataId { get; set; }
}
```

And I have a mapping to bind the array back to a boolean list here:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<RiderOptIn>()
                .HasIndex(entity => new { entity._email, entity._username })
                .IsUnique();

            modelBuilder.Entity<LeaderboardRideResult>().Property(p => p.contents)
             .HasConversion(
                 v => JsonConvert.SerializeObject(v),
                 v => JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<bool>>(v));
                }
```

Deserialization code (Newtonsoft):

```
List<LeaderboardData> myDeserializedClass = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<LeaderboardData>>(result); (result = the JSON above)
```

I'm getting this back:

```
Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: 'Cannot deserialize the current JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) into type 'KiltedRiders.Models.LeaderboardRideResult' because the type requires a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) to deserialize correctly.
To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) or change the deserialized type to an array or a type that implements a collection interface (e.g. ICollection, IList) like List<T> that can be deserialized from a JSON array. JsonArrayAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to deserialize from a JSON array.
Path '[0]._cs_results', line 1, position 90.'
```

Any hints on this would be apprecaited.

Comment: You're trying to deserialize an array of booleans into a `LeaderboardRideResult` object. While that obviously doesn't work it's not clear either how *any* transformation after deserialization the array should provide all data required for `LeaderboardRideResult`. Where should `Id` and `Tag` come from?

Comment: You have 2 problems here. Serialising json to a *view model* class, mapping a *data model* class to the database. Using the same class for both is not a good idea. What's the maximum number of bool values are in the array? Have you considered mapping the bool flags to bits of an int32 / int64 type in the database?

Comment: what database are you using @Nick?

Comment: If you want to have it as an boolean array, as you wrote, why don't you declare it as such? I mean like `public virtual bool[] _cs_results { get; set; }` ? I don't see what `LeaderboardRideResult` is used for in this context.

Comment: Can you provide more details on DB structure you are looking for?
Do you want two tables `LeaderboardData`  and `LeaderboardRideResult`?  or  do you want just one table with json column?

Answer (score 1):

Your C# model is not matching the incoming json type.

`public virtual LeaderboardRideResult _cs_results { get; set; }`
should be like

> `public virtual bool[] _cs_results { get; set; }`

or

> `public virtual List<bool> _cs_results { get; set; }`

Comment: Thanks! This results in 

The property 'LeaderboardData._cs_results' could not be mapped because it is of type 'bool[]', which is not a supported primitive type or a valid entity type. Either explicitly map this property, or ignore it using the '[NotMapped]' attribute or by using 'EntityTypeBuilder.Ignore' in 'OnModelCreating'.

Comment: Entity provides us the feature for Calculated columns or Database Generated columns. At DB side you can create userdefined datatype if required.

Comment: @Nick after using bool[], you would need to set up the conversion manually
`
            modelBuilder.Entity<LeaderboardData>().Property(p => p._cs_results)
             .HasConversion(
                 v => JsonConvert.SerializeObject(v),
                 v => JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<bool>>(v));
                }
`

Answer (score 0):

Add another new property in your model for retrieve data:

```cs
    [NotMapped]
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "_cs_results")]
    public virtual List<bool> CsResult { get; set; }
```

Finally `LeaderboardData` model look like:

```cs
public class LeaderboardData
{

    public int LeaderboardId { get; set; }

    [DefaultValue(1)]
    public int Week { get; set; }
    [NotMapped]
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "_cs_results")]
    public virtual List<bool> CsResult { get; set; }
    public virtual LeaderboardRideResult _cs_results { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: You're suggesting to add a non-mapped property which is explictly named as "_cs_results" for parsing from JSON. But at the same time you keep another mapped property `LeaderboardRideResult _cs_results`. How does that work?

Comment: @Matt ```JsonPropertyAttribute``` Instructs the JsonSerializer to always serialize the member with the specified name.``` LeaderboardRideResult``` is not need to serialize 
 this property (CsResult ).I am not change any previous property thats why it is stay here.

Comment: Right, but my point was, we have then `CsResult`  (with `PropertyName = "_cs_results"`) and also `_cs_results` of type `LeaderBoardRideResult` - which seems to be a contradiction. I have also asked @Nick about this, since I think the question is not asked clearly enough.

Answer (score -1):

Your json should be parseable and can be converted as an object. In case of your model structure, it is not.
I can't see the relationship on your sample models, but you can try creating an entity for your Content property, like this:

```
public class Content 
{
    public int Id { get;set; }
    public bool Value { get;set; }

    [ForeignKey("LeaderboardRideResult")]
    public int LeaderboardRideResultId { get; set; }

    public virtual LeaderboardRideResult LeaderboardRideResult { get;set; }
}
```

And here, I updated minor name on your 2 existing models:

```
public class LeaderboardData
{
    [Key]
    public int LeaderboardId { get; set; }

    [DefaultValue(1)]
    public int Week { get; set; }
    ......

    public virtual LeaderboardRideResult LeaderboardRideResult { get; set; }
}

public class LeaderboardRideResult
{
    [Key]
    public int LeaderboardRideResultId { get; set; }

    public string Tag { get; set; }

    ...

    [ForeignKey("LeaderboardData")]
    public int LeaderboardDataId { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Content> Contents { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: take a look again, public ICollection<Content> Contents { get; set; }